# Asterisk issue with IVR and '1' extension number

Tags: voip, asterisk, freepbx

I have FreePBX 15 installation. I have successfully added multiple extensions.

Numbers include some three digit numbers and '1' extension which is a normal ip-phone like others with exactly the same configuration.

I can call them with no issue. I have also set up an IVR which has no entries, it just allows to direct dial all extensions.
It works for all of them except for '1'.

Example for '213':

```
app_read.c: User entered '213'  
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:10] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000002", "0?#,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:11] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000002", "0?t,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:12] ExecIf("PJSIP/x-00000002", "1?Set(LOCALEXT=1)") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:13] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000002", "0?i,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:14] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000002", "1?from-did-direct-ivr,2137,1") in new stack 
VERBOSE[6729][C-00000003] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (from-did-direct-ivr,213,1)
```

And the call is successful. However for '1':

```
app_read.c: User entered '1'    
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:10] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000003", "0?#,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:11] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000003", "0?t,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:12] ExecIf("PJSIP/x-00000003", "1?Set(LOCALEXT=1)") in new stack   
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:13] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000003", "1?i,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (ivr-1,i,1) 
VERBOSE[10123][C-00000004] pbx.c: Executing [i@ivr-1:1] Set("PJSIP/x-00000003", "INVALID_LOOPCOUNT=1") in new stack
```

I get error: invalid destination

I have also tried to add IVR entry for '1' to redirect it to '1' extension.

```
app_read.c: User entered '1'    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:10] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000001", "0?#,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:11] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000001", "0?t,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:12] ExecIf("PJSIP/x-00000001", "1?Set(LOCALEXT=1)") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:13] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000001", "0?i,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:14] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000001", "1?from-did-direct-ivr,1,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[6334][C-00000002] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (from-did-direct-ivr,1,1)    
WARNING[6334][C-00000002] pbx.c: Channel 'PJSIP/x-00000001' sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=from-did-direct-ivr,1,1
```

When I add IVR entry for '2' to redirect to '1' it works:

```
app_read.c: User entered '2'    
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:10] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000011", "0?#,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:11] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000011", "0?t,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:12] ExecIf("PJSIP/x-00000011", "0?Set(LOCALEXT=1)") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:13] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000011", "0?i,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:14] GotoIf("PJSIP/x-00000011", "0?from-did-direct-ivr,2,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [s@ivr-1:15] Goto("PJSIP/x-00000011", "2,1") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (ivr-1,2,1) 
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [2@ivr-1:1] Set("PJSIP/x-00000011", "__ivrreturn=0") in new stack   
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx.c: Executing [2@ivr-1:2] Goto("PJSIP/x-00000011", "from-did-direct,1,1") in new stack    
VERBOSE[30910][C-00000012] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (from-did-direct,1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you have no 1 extension

```
 invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=from-did-direct-ivr,1,1
```

Why you have no - it is enother question. I can suggest you find from-did-direct-ivr context and see if it is there.

All files are in /etc/asterisk/ folder

Side note: from-did-direct-ivr and from-did-direct are DIFFERENT contexts.